# Tweaking Op Amp Emitter Follower

Tags: operational-amplifier

This thread has been wrongly closed.The question was clear and !received one excellent reply to prove it. Let's hope it gets reopened.

Please refer to attached LTSpice screenshot below.

The amp works as in the sim, except max amplitude out is 4.7Vpp and not approx 10V as in the sim. I substituted an LM358 for the LT1006 (not in stock). Am I correct in thinking the voltage difference is because the LM358 is not rail-to-rail, or is there another reason?

As drawn, the offset and gain are interactive. This makes adjustment fiddly. What is the simplest way to mod the circuit so the gain adjustment does not affect the offset and vice versa? I would like to keep the amp direct coupled, i.e. no caps in the signal path. Note: R11 and R9 are nominal values for each side of the 10K pot.

Any other suggestions would also be greatly appreciated.

[image: LTSpice Op Amp]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: stacksolutions, talk about the application and your expectations. It may be that you think you know how all this works and/or should work. But let others into your head. We may notice something important to consider.

Comment: Have you tried simulating it with an LM358 model?

Comment: The difference is far too great to be explained by the op-amp swap. I suspect the issue is in the implementation, maybe the 2N2222 is backwards, shorted or something of that ilk. There are also some criminally bad "2N3055"s to be found in some marketplaces.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ideas that come to mind.

The darlington pair emitter follower (Q2 and Q3) will have a difference of \$2\times 0.7V=1.4V\$ (or worse) between input and output, at high load. The LM385 output will not get closer than 1.5V to its positive supply, so you have lost a total of nearly 3V already from the 12V available.

You can recover 0.7V or so, by using a sziklai pair instead of a darlington arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm1tWB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As far as the op-amp is concerned, in your design, offset and signal are mixed to a single potential, and applied to the non-inverting input. Necessarily that arrangement will apply the same gain indiscriminately to both.

For a single op-amp solution, I suggest that you exploit the summing junction at the inverting input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6rWsy.png)</sup>

Gain \$G\$ applied to the signal at A is set by varying VR1:

$$ G = -\frac{R_2}{R_1 + VR_1} $$

An offset is applied by injecting current into the summing junction, the non-inverting input. That current is set by VR2. Since the summing junction is fixed at +6V (or whatever potential you apply to the non-inverting input), this current is independent of VR1, and the offset won't be affected.

Regardless of gain set by VR1, turning VR2 will always produce the same change in output per degree of rotation of VR2.

Unfortunately, the signal at A is inverted, which may be a deal breaker. Of course, the LM358 has two op-amps, and you can always use that to un-invert. If you're happy to employ that second op-amp, I'm sure there's a much more elegant and less algebraically taxing solution. Before I address that, let me know why this one isn't good enough.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for. I would use a 78L06 for V1 and 2, and maybe substitute a rail-to-rail single supply op amp like an LT1006 for the LM358. If I need non-inverted output can I use a transistor before the 2N2222 for phase inversion?

Comment: Sadly this thread has been closed by Stack. I wanted to interact further. Maybe I will need to start a new topic. Sorry for any inconvenience. Hope to hear from you again.

Comment: @stacksolutions We are asking you politely for follow or try the above suggestions. We all learned this stuff the hard way, so making "what if" changes are important.  By the way, a 10nf feedback capacitor from the op-amp output to the inverting input will make it very stable, as well as a 10uf fromm Vcc to gnd.